# How to use Switch Case in C# for decimal values

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am converting a code from VB.net to C#. Since new to C# i got stuck on **Switch()** statement for **Decimals**. I found out that i can not use decimal values in switch statement.

VB switch statement looks like this :

changeAmt is decimal

> Select Case changeAmt
>
> ```
> Case Is > 0
> ```
>
> > ```
> >              expressions
> > ```
>
> ```
> Case Is < 0
> ```
>
> > ```
> >              expressions
> > ```

How can i convert this into C#?

Do i have to use if-else statements. I want to use switch because it will make the code much easier to write and understand

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is using decimal ranges in a switch impossible in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937154/is-using-decimal-ranges-in-a-switch-impossible-in-c)

Comment: If you are working with intervals, you could create an enum to represent each interval, get the enum from the decimal value and use it on the switch/case statement.

Comment: Oh, enum... just posted that as an answer

Comment: @MareInfinitus some credit would be interesting =)

Comment: Came up with that idea myself, read your comment afterwards. but okay :-)

Answer (score 4):

You have to use `if` statements for this. You could cast the value to a different type, but you still can't use conditions in a `case`.

So:

```
if (changeAmt > 0) {
  ...
} else if (changeAmt < 0) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: i guess i have to use if-else as the cases have conditions in them

Comment: OP says he does not want to use if-else

Comment: @MareInfinitus: Yes, and I have explained that it's not possible with those requirements.

Comment: With the small indirection, it is possible. As almost anything in programming ;)

Comment: @MareInfinitus: What you are suggesting is to first use `if` statements to determine a state, then use a `switch` to act on the state. That's not using a `switch` *instead* of the `if` statements.

Answer (score 2):

What you still can do is a single level of indirection. It makes more 
clear what you want to express and leaves the structure as you like it.
And, you can use this conversion everywhere you want to use your decimal 
switch. Quite plain, isn't it?

Here is some easy code to show what I want to tell:

```
    public enum EnumChangeAmt
    {
        Undetermined,
        Negative,
        Positive,
        ExactlyNull,
    }

    public class EnumSwitchSample
    {
        public void EnumSwitch()
        {
            var changeAmt = 0;

            var changeAmtType = GetChangeAmt(changeAmt);

            switch (changeAmtType)
            {
                case EnumChangeAmt.Negative:
                {
                    break;
                }
                case EnumChangeAmt.Positive:
                {
                    break;
                }
                case EnumChangeAmt.ExactlyNull:
                {
                    break;
                }
                case EnumChangeAmt.Undetermined:
                default:
                {
                    // do something about it
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        public EnumChangeAmt GetChangeAmt(int changeAmt)
        {
            if (changeAmt < 0)
            {
                return EnumChangeAmt.Negative;
            }

            if (changeAmt > 0)
            {
                return EnumChangeAmt.Positive;
            }

            if (changeAmt == 0)
            {
                return EnumChangeAmt.ExactlyNull;
            }

            return EnumChangeAmt.Undetermined;
        }
    }
```

As Andre Calil stated, enums are very useful here!

Comment: this was useful. gud example. thnx a ton

Comment: Bit long, don't you think!? Why not this. if (changeAmt > 0) { ... } else if (changeAmt < 0) { ... }

Comment: I always write the parentheses as i think it is more clear then and easier to change. And, I personally do not like a return on the same line as the if statement is.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `if-else`.  In C# the switch statement only cases that are constant values.

Answer (score 1):

A `Select Case` statement in VB.Net supports a much wider range of expressions than a `switch` statement in C#.  A C# `switch` is essentially limited to numeric and string constants while `Select Case` can support arbitrary expressions.  When porting a `Select Case` that doesn't fit into the range of a C# `switch` you should use an `if / else` statement

```
if (changeAmt > 0) { 
  // expressions 
} else if (changeAmt < 0) {
  // expressions
}
```

Comment: thanx all for the quick support and guidance

Answer (score 1):

you can only swicth on specific values in C# so in your particular case you'd need to use an if else if:

```
if(changeAmt < 0){
} else if (changeAmt > 0)
{
} else 
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> The switchstatement only supports integral types (enumerations are not
>   listed but can be used with switch statements because they are backed
>   by an integral type)(strings are also supported as pointed out by
>   Changeling - see the comment for reference) and equality comparisons
>   with constant values. Therefore you have to use some if statements.

Can you use if else?

if(Is > 0)

```
             expressions
```

else if(Is < 0)

```
             expressions
```

[Is using decimal ranges in a switch impossible in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937154/is-using-decimal-ranges-in-a-switch-impossible-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest to read solution is to use an if-else block.

```
if (changeAmt > 0)
{
    // blablabla
}
else if (changeAmt < 0)
{
    // blablabla
}
```

Not sure why it was a switch case in VB, seems unnescessary.

Answer (score 0):

For `decimals` you can use `if` and `if-else` statements.

like

```
if(condition)
{

}
else if(condition)
{

}
```