# Example of Switch Statements

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, switch-statement

If the total of this textbox is: PostDiscountTextBox.Text = $500.00, how do we make Switch statements stating that if the Post-discount Cost amount is between 0.00 and 999.99, display a message box with the message of "This amount qualifies for 'A-100' frequent flier miles" and an "OK" button?

**Will someone provide an example of a switch statement?**

I only have this so far, and I don't think it follows anything at all. Will someone guide me through this? Thank you.

```
        switch (PostDiscountCostTextBox.Text)
        {
            case (0.00 < && PostDiscountCostTextBox.Text <= 999.00)
```

Thank everyone who helped, but I am trying to figure out how to use a switch statement that evaluates Post-discount Cost based on a range of numeric values (nothing about an if statement). Yes, many cases will be put, and these will be my first two cases. Will someone be kind enough to provide me an example so that I could fill the rest of my cases in? I have lots. Thank you.

If the Post-discount Cost amount is **between 0.00 and 999.99**, display a message box with the message of "This amount qualifies for 'A-100' frequent flier miles." and an "OK" button. No title bar text or icon should be used.

If the Post-discount Cost amount is **between 1,000.00 and 1,499.99**, display a message box with the message of "This amount qualifies for 'B-500' frequent flier miles." and an "OK" button. No title bar text or icon should be used.

Comment: If you have only one condition, you don't need `switch`, you can use just one `if`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is using decimal ranges in a switch impossible in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937154/is-using-decimal-ranges-in-a-switch-impossible-in-c)

Comment: well...it was constructive for me.  upvoted

Comment: My first thought would be to utilize Ternary operands to make this more efficient. Something like `double amt = PostDiscountCostTextBox.Text; report(0 < amt <= 999.99 ? "A-100 : 1000 < amt < 1499.99 ? "B-500" : ... : exception("Error in calculation"));` where `report(message)` displays the appropriate value whatever format you require or works through the exception thrown to display an appropriate message.

Answer (score 31):

That kind of [`switch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) usage is not allowed in C#.

Here is an example of proper `switch` usage

```
switch(n)       
{         
   case 1:   
      cost += 25;
      break;                  
   case 2:            
      cost += 25;
      break;           
   case 3:            
      cost += 50;
      break;         
   default:            
      Console.WriteLine("Invalid selection. Please select 1, 2, or 3.");            
      break;      
 }
```

Your example should be transform into `if-elseif-else` statement:

```
if(first_case_predicate)
{

}
else if(another_predicate)
{

}
else
{
    // like 'default' of switch
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot check for ranges in `switch`, you should use a chain of `else if`. See [Is using decimal ranges in a switch impossible in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937154/is-using-decimal-ranges-in-a-switch-impossible-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

The straightforward way is to use `if else` statements as the ranges check are not allowed for the `switch` operation. The another tricky way is to use `Dictionaries`. The below code snippet is a demonstration of what you want using the second approach.

```
decimal myVal = decimal.Parse(PostDiscountCostTextBox.Text);

        var conditions = new Dictionary<Func<int, bool>, Action>
        { 
            { x => x > 0 && x <= 999 ,    () => Console.WriteLine("This amount qualifies for 'A-100' frequent flier miles.")   } ,
            { x => x > 999 ,   () => Console.WriteLine("Dummy!")  } ,
        };

        cases.First(kvp => kvp.Key(myNum)).Value();
```

Not so easy as the `if else` approach, but desreves a test.