# How to add the results of a case

Tags: vb.net, switch-statement, format-currency

I am trying to display the results of this case and format the total amount in currency. However, It's not working and I am not quite sure why? Could someone please take a look at my code and tell me if you see what my eyes cannot. I just need a second pair of eyes on this one. Thank you!

```
Select Case ApplianceButton
        Case "Refrigerator"
            Label17.Text = FormatCurrency(kwVal).ToString
        Case "TV"
            Label19.Text = FormatCurrency(kwVal).ToString
        Case "Fan"
            Label21.Text = FormatCurrency(kwVal).ToString
        Case "Space Heater"
            Label23.Text = FormatCurrency(kwVal).ToString
        Case "Oven"
            Label25.Text = FormatCurrency(kwVal).ToString
        Case "Dryer"
            Label27.Text = FormatCurrency(kwVal).ToString
        Case "Laundry Washer"
            Label29.Text = FormatCurrency(kwVal).ToString

Label30.Text = Int((kwVal(Label17.Text) + kwVal(Label19.Text) 
    + kwVal(Label21.Text) + kwVal(Label23.Text) + kwVal(Label25.Text) 
    + kwVal(Label27.Text) + kwVal(Label29.Text)))
```

Comment: Are you trying to use a switch statement?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15046553/example-of-switch-statements

Comment: It is a select case statement, each case is an appliance and each appliance inherits a currency variable from the user input. I need to be able to add those values and provide a grand total

Comment: Currently I am getting an error BC30690 "Structure Decimal cannot be indexed because it has no default property

Comment: What are you trying to do with `kwVal(Label17.Text)`?

Comment: According to MSDN this is the answer on how to fix this issue, "An attempt was made to use default property syntax with a structure that has no default property.
Error ID: BC30690
To correct this error
Use standard property syntax to access the structure's properties."  I have no idea what that means!

Comment: kwVal is the variable name, it stands for kilowatts value (Energy Costs)

Comment: I apologize I forgot to show the entire code that shows the declaration. Dim kwVal As Decimal = TotalCostofOperation.Text
        TotalCostofOperation.Text = FormatCurrency(kwVal)

Comment: 1) Have you tried putting in a break point to see which line is giving you issues? 
2) Can you post the entire method(Sub)?  It may make it a bit easier to understand. If I am understanding correctly, ApplianceButton is a string, and you are trying to update a different label depending on what that string is?

Comment: Ok I will repost this with the entire code segment.

Comment: I know `kwVal` is a variable: What do you think `kwVal(Label17.Text)` means? That's what the error is complaining about. It doesn't make sense. If you explain what you are trying to do with that line, we can tell you how to do it correctly.

Answer (score -1):

The `Appliancebutton` should be the value that should display or provide the name of your appliances, then than makes `Dim Appliancebutton as string` ?

then if you say that your Appliance button was clicked or in any kind of event that happened, then the value of `Appliancebutton=` should be either `"Refrigerator" or "TV" or "Fan" etc...`

to use `Formatcurrency` function, then `kwVal` should be an integer or double etc... right?

and then on the grand total, the `kwVal(Label17.Text)`, seems like you are trying to multiply `kwVal` and the `Label17.Text`...

your symbol should be an asterisk * and you can't possibly multiply a string and an integer, then if it would help, use `Convert.toint32(label17.text)`, to complete the equation, though it may be long, I prefer `kwVal*(Convert.toint32(label17.text)` ?

Just making a guess... I don't know if this is right or helpful to you.