# How to compare values from textbox in a switch statement?

Tags: c#, textbox, switch-statement

I am a beginner at C# and I am trying to compare a value in a text box (which should be either N, S, E, or W) and then use a switch statement to determine the cost of a package based on the zone typed into said text box.

```
decimal N = 27;
decimal S = 36;
decimal E = 45;
decimal W = 54;
decimal ZoneCost = 0;

switch (textboxZone.Text)
{
    case N:
      ZoneCost = 27;
      break;

    case S:
      ZoneCost = 36;
      break;    

    etc.
}
```

What I want to happen is the ZoneCost variable to change depending on which letter (or "zone") is typed in.
I keep getting an error saying it can't implicitly convert decimal to string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is using decimal ranges in a switch impossible in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937154/is-using-decimal-ranges-in-a-switch-impossible-in-c)

Comment: This is what we call an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/). You want to X and thought “Hey, I bet if I compared `textboxZone.Text` against decimal 27 that would X!” But you found it didn't X. We can help you if you explained what X is. To start, show us what `textboxZone.Text` contains, and explain where 27, 36, and such come from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good place to use the new C# 8.0 switch expressions:

```
int cost = textboxZone.Text switch {
    "N" => 27,
    "S" => 36,
    "E" => 45,
    "W" => 54,
    _ => throw new Exception("not valid input")
};
```

The reason your code isn't working is that you are comparing a string (textboxZone.Text) to a decimal (the variables N, S, E, W).  Throw double-quote marks around your switch clauses:

```
case "N":
```

Comment: Thank you that worked! I never even thought of that!

Answer (score 0):

In a more native/closer to the metal C-Style style language, such a check might have worked. If you had picked the proper ASCII/Unicode values, that is.

As a general rule, string comparision are finiky and a pain in the behind. The problems starts at casing, goes over whitespaces and ends around normalisation. As far as processing in any form is concerned, the only type *worse* then string I can think of is raw binary. I avoid it. Even if I was the one that wrote it to the UI, I prefer getting the input another way/another format. It is a nessesarily evil when working with a user or XML/Rest/similar Service.

I would organize the Letter/Number pair into a struct, class or tupel called `PackageSize`. Create a array of list of `PackageSize`. Then give the UI a ComboBox with manual input disabeled. Fill the CB from the array, each entry using the Letter for display and the ArrayIndex as value. And then only care about the selected value, rather then what is displayed for further processing. ComboBoxes can give you a nice, solid Integer this way that can be use to look up the values in the collection it was build from.

A switch/case doing string matching can work and is propably easier for now and reliably enough, if you keep to english letters. But I avoid giving the user the option to input soemthing I can not process. And and once you got the UI creation/input matching down, arrays of values are easier to expand longterm.